# Remove message delay in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I tried spam with a bot in discord.py but there is a delay between sending the messages. It sends five messages in a row and there is the delay. How can I remove the delay?

Thanks for the helps in advance!

Comment: Please share your code. Without the code we cannot help you.

Comment: Ratelimits. You can only send 5 messages per 5 seconds per channel, if you send 5 messages in one second, you’ll have to wait 4 till you can send more.

Comment: You can't. The purpose of ratelimits is to stop you from spamming Discord's API, so there's not gonna be a way to remove it in order to go on and spam it.

Comment: Are citing if the user sending a message is a bot? Otherwise it’ll trigger its own message. Also, please share the code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Without your code, we cannot fix this. However, it seems like you are getting rate-limited.

One way to fix this is to save lines and print that.
What your bot is doing:

```
await ctx.send("sussy baka")
await ctx.send("sussy baka")
await ctx.send("sussy baka")
await ctx.send("sussy baka")
```

What we can change it to is

```
await ctx.send("sussy baka \n sussy baka \n sussy baka")
```

by saving a string like this:

```
str+="Test"
```

for each message

Answer (score 0):

Following [chess_lover_6 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69106814/4298200),

You can also use a for loop to do this.

```
import math
from math import sqrt
msg = "Hello world"
for i in range(int(sqrt(10))):
    msg += "\n" + msg
await ctx.send(msg)
```

This will print the message according to the number of times we want accurately unlike my first approach

This will add a newline and then add the message. We then only send it once. I think this way you won't get rate limited.

```
msg = ["Hello World"]
count = 10 # Number of times to send message
for i in range(count - 1):
    msg.extend(["\n", "Hello World"])
await ctx.send("".join(msg)) #sends Hello World 10 times
```

*Note: I have not tested this with discord.py. Although I have tested it by printing on the terminal.*

Comment: This will print the Hello world 10 times. Although there is a problem. If we want to print it three times, then it will print only 2 times

Comment: I have added another approach which is better.

Comment: Make sure to be careful. Discord has a character limit so your message may not get sent due to that limit.